# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and PHP Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array

Tags: php

The objective is that matched ids are removed, returning the remaining values in an array.

This is my script:

```php
function example($link, $onlist)
{
    //$newarray = array();
    $newarray = implode(',', $onlist);
    foreach ($newarray as $key)
    {
        $query = mysql_query("select * from table where id = '".$newarray."'");
        $existing = array();
        while($cz = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $existing[] = $cz['id'];
        }
    }

    $ex = array_diff($newarray, $existing);
    return $ex;
}
```

If I run this script. It shows errors:

> PHP Warning:  array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array Warning:
>   Invalid argument supplied for foreach() .

Please share suggestions with me.

Comment: $existing array should be declared outside of the loop. and check the values of  $existing array using debug functions like print_r or var_dump. Use as it is instead of implode

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because after running `implode` on the  `$newarray` it is  converted into string that's why it's giving you that error. For more info check php manual

https://www.php.net/implode

`implode` returns string

Answer (score 0):

After Imploding those values using comma,You cant foreach those values.

Because the values stored in $newarray will be like value1,value2,value3,etc...

SO you cant foreach it...

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
function example($link, $onlist)
{
  $newarray = array();
  $existing = array();
  $onlist = is_array($onlist) ? $onlist : array($onlist);

  if(!empty($onlist)){
    $newarray = $onlist;

    foreach ($onlist as $key)
    {

        $query = mysql_query("select * from table where id = '".$key."'");

        while($cz = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

        {

            $existing[] = $cz['id'];

        }



    }

}


    return array_diff($newarray, $existing);

}
```

Comment: No.. Same issues are coming. I have doubt, after implode the array. can I write the foreach() method? Is it right or not?

Answer (score 0):

A few things I notice:

1. `implode()` takes an array and turns into a string. Depending on what `$onlist` is, you probably want to `explode()` (if it's a string) or just use it as-is (if it's an array). I'm going to assume it's a comma-separated string.
2. `mysql_*` methods are deprecated. You should use alternatives, such as [`mysqli_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).
3. The MySQL query is getting all rows rows where `id` is `$newarray`. It should be getting instead all rows where `id` is `$key`.
4. Since you're only interested in the `id` field from the database, you should only be requesting that column (otherwise, you're moving all the rest of the columns over for no reason).
5. It looks like in your table `id` is a unique value. You can probably save some processing and just grab the first returned row (if any).
6. You are reseting `$existing` every time you check a new `id`. You only want to reset it once at the beginning.
7. Your function `example` receives `$link` variable which is never used.

So, based on all that, here's a version of your code that should work:

```php
function example($link, $onlist)
{
    // Convert the comma-separated string to an array
    $newarray = explode(',', $onlist);
    
    // Start an empty array
    $existing = array();
    
    // Collect all the ids that are found in the database
    foreach ($newarray as $key)
    {
        $query = mysqli_query("SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '" . $key . "';");
        if($cz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $existing[] = $cz['id'];
        }
    }

    // Get only the ids that were NOT found
    $ex = array_diff($newarray, $existing);
    
    return $ex;
}
```

One important thing to note with your strategy is that you'll do one MySQL query for every single ID you want to match. You can also do this in a single query, which will often be much better for performance, especially if `id` is an index to your table:

```php
function example($link, $onlist)
{   
    // Convert $onlist from "a,b,c,1,2,3" to "'a','b','c','1','2','3'"
    $tmp_array = explode(',', $onlist);
    $onlist = "'" . implode("','", $tmp_array) . "'";
    
    // Start an empty array
    $existing = array();
    
    // Get *all* rows that have *any* of the IDs in $onlist
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (" . $key . ");");
    while($cz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $existing[] = $cz['id'];
    }
    
    // Keep only the ids that were NOT found
    $ex = array_diff($newarray, $existing);
    
    return $ex;
}
```

Comment: I am trying this example, But it shows errors: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in ,PHP Warning:  array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array in ... These errors are showing. give me suggestion please..